# Salesforce: Visualforce pages not working anymore because of certificate error

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a dev box running with a namespace and just added a demo visualforce page named "test" and just clicked on "Preview". It is ending up with a certificate error on my browser.

The URL salesforce tries to open is https://myinstance-dev-dev--mynamespace.visualforce.com/apex/test
The certificate being provided by this domain is for "viv1.force.com". That is why my browser is blocking it.

Any idea why this is happening? My visualforce pages were working on the dev box, but now suddenly end up with this error.

Comment: 1. It's bad idea to call apex class or vf page "Test" or any other "system" name, you might get interesting errors. 2. Are all steps in Setup -> My Domain completed? 3. "something.force.com" typically indicates you have community enabled. What is that page doing, trying to redirect somewhere? Or is it normal VF, some data, some html? Do you have critical updates preview? Maybe try turning on/off the ones that have "Edge" and "Stabilize" in them in https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_cruc.htm

Comment: My domain is completed. I have the CTI dumm adapter installed with the demoAdapterPage which is also not working. My test page is doing nothing, it is the default visual force page printing out a dummy text. Will check the updates stuff. Fact is, Visualforce pages were working, and suddenly stopped. Wasn't changing anything in the org.

Answer (score 1):

Strange solution. Had to check "Critical updates" on setup, and DEACTIVATED the setting "Stabilize URLs for Visualforce, Experience Builder, Site.com Studio, and Content Files". Now it is working again.

I assume for some reason this stabilization missed to change the used certificate behind visualforce pages. Deactivating above option fixed it.

Comment: See if turning it back on reproduces the issue. You might want to contact support. When the update gets auto enforced you don't want to be left hanging with broken page and even if support will help you with some emergency tweaks - might take a while for cert and DNS entry to propagate if it's been cached... Glad I could send you to the crit updates page :)